# Counting rows between two dates on JOIN

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have two Tables named String and Float

```
String
|               DateAndTime           | Val |
---------------------------------------------
|       2016-07-26 18:35:31.000       | AX2 |
|       2016-07-26 18:30:31.000       | G27 |
|       2016-07-26 18:25:31.000       | AX2 |
|       2016-07-26 18:20:31.000       | AX2 |
|       2016-07-26 18:20:31.000       | G27 |

Float
|               DateAndTime           | Val | Marker |
------------------------------------------------------
|       2016-07-26 18:31:31.000       | 234 |   X    |
|       2016-07-26 18:26:31.000       | 612 |   y    |
|       2016-07-26 18:21:31.000       | 12  |   a    |
|       2016-07-26 18:21:31.000       | 123 |   f    |
```

From these two tables I want to get the min and max date from each `Val` in the string table that has occurred in the past 24 hours and display that information.  I also want to count every row that was inserted into the float table between the min and max time of each `Val` and display that along side.

Below is my query.  The part that that queries the `StringTable` works great and I get the results I expected.  I then tried to do a `JOIN` on the Float table and count the rows.

```
    SELECT
    S.Batch,
    COUNT(F.DateAndTime) AS DataPointsRecorded,
    S.CycleStart,
    S.LastRecordedTime
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
                 Val AS Batch,
                 MIN(DateAndTime) AS CycleStart, 
                 MAX(DateAndTime) AS LastRecordedTime
        FROM     dbo.StringTable
        WHERE    DATEDIFF(HOUR,DateAndTime, GETDATE()) < 24
        AND      Val IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY Val
    ) S 
JOIN     dbo.FloatTable F ON S.CycleStart = F.DateAndTime
GROUP BY S.Batch, S.CycleStart, S.LastRecordedTime
ORDER BY CycleStart desc, Batch
```

This resulted in every `DataPointsRecorded` coming out as the same exact number for every row.

I then changed how I joined the two tables using

`JOIN dbo.FloatTable F ON F.DateAndTime BETWEEN S.CycleStart AND S.LastRecordedTime`

And that just resulted in very large numbers in each row for DataPoints.

My expected results would be something like this based off the example I gave earlier.

```
| Batch | DataPoint |          CycleStart         |               LastRecordedTime        |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  AX2  |     4     |   2016-07-26 18:20:31.000       |     2016-07-26 18:35:31.000       |
|  G27  |     3     |   2016-07-26 18:20:31.000       |     2016-07-26 18:30:31.000       |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this ( I removed the group by of the 2 columns CycleStart, LastRecordedTime )

```
    SELECT
    S.Batch,
    COUNT(F.DateAndTime) AS DataPointsRecorded,
    Min(S.CycleStart) as CycleStart ,
    Max(S.LastRecordedTime) as LastRecordedTime
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
                 Val AS Batch,
                 MIN(DateAndTime) AS CycleStart, 
                 MAX(DateAndTime) AS LastRecordedTime
        FROM     dbo.StringTable
        WHERE    DATEDIFF(HOUR,DateAndTime, GETDATE()) < 24
        AND      Val IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY Val
    ) S 
JOIN     dbo.FloatTable F ON F.DateAndTime BETWEEN S.CycleStart AND S.LastRecordedTime
GROUP BY S.Batch -- S.CycleStart -- S.LastRecordedTime Commented out the last 2
ORDER BY CycleStart desc, Batch
```

**Edit:** 
Explanation

The reason why you were seeing more data with your query was because you were aggregating it at a more granular level that included timestamps which forces sql to include all unique combinations of the Batch+CycleStart+LastRecordedTime

Comment: I took back my comment, sorry for the confusion.  The test database I was on had some broken data.  Your answer did help get the results I expected.  Thank you.